# Bootstrap: How to make a background image sit between the edge of the container and the edge of the body?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I'm currently in the process of developing a site using Twitter Bootstrap. In the site's design I have a background-image which sits between the edge of the container and the edge of the body.

Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
section {
   background-image: url('example.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: bottom right;
}
```

The code above simply applies a background-image to the bottom right of my section. I need to ensure that the background-image is at the maximum width it can be without intercepting the container.

Here's a diagram which might better explain what I'm looking to do.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YYVv.jpg)

How do I go about achieving this effect without the use of jQuery/Javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the code that you've tried so far

Comment: Need your current code, otherwise it's impossible to say

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want--

Go full page to see it.

**check snippet**

```css
.container-fluid  {
   background: url('http://www.jonomus.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Screenshot_2015-10-20-10-06-10.png');
   background-position: right bottom;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 130px 130px;
}
.col-xs-6 {
  background-color:yellow;
  color: red;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       </head>
      
<body>
    <section>
    <div class="container-fluid ">
       
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                    <h1>Lorem Ipsum.</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use container-fluid instead of section..use col-xs-6 other-wise it will cover whole page

Answer (score 0):

**CSS only** - without the use of jQuery/Javascript

As you may know, the Bootstrap `.container` pixel width changes depending on the screen width. There are 3 separate media queries used for this. You can adjust the background image size in the same way, at each Bootstrap breakpoint..

```
section {
   min-height: 100vh;
   background-image: url('//placehold.it/300');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: right bottom; 
   background-attachment: fixed;
}    

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    section {
        background-size: calc((100% - 750px)/2);
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    section {
        background-size: calc((100% - 970px)/2);
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    section {
        background-size: calc((100% - 1170px)/2);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/985dNICmvQ

Note: On the `xs` screen, the container becomes 100% width so your background image will disappear.